# "Compass Interference" message even after navigator.compass.clearWatch

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm running a PhoneGap 1.5 / jQuery Mobile 1.1RC1 app built on an iPhone.  One of my pages is a compass page.  I start the compass with:

```
watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(success, fail, {frequency: 100});
```

And then when the page shuts down, I call:

```
navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchID);
```

I've verified with alert statements that the watchID is correct in each case.  However, after the page transitions to the other parts of my app, I get "Compass Interference" messages from iOS whenever I set the phone next to my computer.  Although there may indeed be compass interference, I've shut down the compass watchHeading listener... so why are these messages still showing up?  And more importantly, how can I get rid of them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this one can be chalked up to a PhoneGap bug in 1.5.  The issue has disappeared now that I'm on PhoneGap 2.0